# Power Consumption for DDR3L SDRAM IC's

Tags: power-supply, power, non-volatile-memory, ddr3, zynq

Designing a board that will utilize some DDR3L memory for the first time and looking to gain some confidence in some steps I've assumed/taken so far.

I plan to use two 4Gb SDRAM IC's (MT41K256M16TW-107) in a single rank 32-bit wide configuration interfacing to a Zynq 7000 device. (XC7Z020-1CLG400C) This maximizes the Zynq's memory controller capabilities. Same architecture as that found on the Zybo Z7 (020) eval board from Digilent. In my post I'm looking for help on the power supply requirements and clocking.

First assumption... can I assume that even though the memory IC is listed as DDR3-1866 on Micron's website for the product listing, that I can still provide a 533MHz clock for transfer rate of 1033MT/s? I assume this rating is just an upper limit for the IC rather than hard window? I think this is true based on the fact that products listed as DDR3-1033 are listed as obsolete.

Next up, power consumption. I used their DDR3 System Power Calculator tool and came up with following, I'll need to multiply this figure by two since I'm using two chips. This tool also doesn't provide much insight into peak power numbers, but based on graphs/waveforms in the tech note, might be safe to double the number and go from there for derating. The Zybo board shows a 1.35V output capable of 1.2A so I'm thinking I'll be fine somewhere in the range of 1.2A to 2A to be on the safe side.

[image: DDR3L Power consumption]

These values are calculated with the following assumptions for page hit rate, percentage of time wr/rd cycles,etc. This is the part I don't have experience with to know how to accurately estimate. I think these defaults are okay based on the tech note here:
https://www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/technical-note/dram/tn41_01ddr3_power.pdf

[image: Usage assumptions]

Looking for help from those who have implemented DDR memory on their boards and any gotcha's that you guys/gals learned in the process. Thanks! (I know I can basically copy specs from the eval board and such but I wouldn't learn much that way. I also want to know more detailed numbers since my project will be battery-based)

Comment: Are you trying to estimate max power to determine what power supply to use, or average power to estimate battery life? Or both?

Comment: Good question, I’m more interested in max power for sizing the power supply. While I intend to have the option of this being battery powered, I’m not exactly interested in optimizing battery life.

Comment: The most significant design choice from a power perspective is your CA topology. Terminated fly-by is easiest, but consumes more power. Unterminated T-topology reduces power consumption. But is a bit more difficult to route.